# Fully Left-Justify When Using atop()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotmath

How can I fully left-justify text when using `atop()`?

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = str_c("atop(bold(", cyl, "~long~text~on~the~top),(shorttext))")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl, labeller = label_parsed) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Comment: `str_c("atop(bold(", cyl, "),(X))")`?

Comment: This gets closer, but doesn't quite solve the problem, I will update my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays I would certainly answer this using the fantastic `ggtext` package

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtext)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = str_c("**", cyl, " long text on the top**<br>(shorttext)")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(hp, wt)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_markdown(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>